# What is $\beta$ doing exactly in Python's Holt's Forecast Method (Double Exponential Smoothing)?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, trend

I am using Holt's Method for forecasting timeseries and try to understand what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are doing.

[image]

$\alpha$ for level control is fine for me: if it's $0$, it's like a normal mean and all observations are equally weighted.
If $\alpha=1$, than it is the naive method, and the last observation will be choosen for next prediction.
This are the two extremes in the interval $[0,1]$.

So now, $\beta$ is controlling trend of the timeseries. But what does this exactly mean?

What happens if I choose $\beta=0$ or $\beta=1$? Is it taking the slopes and then doing the same like with $\alpha$ like when I choose $\beta=1$ it does only consider the last slope?

Thank you in advance, guys!

Comment: $\alpha=0$ looks to me as if it is saying the previous estimated level plus the previous estimated change, without adjusting for the most recent observation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\beta =0$ gives $b_t=b_{t-1}$ so the trend, the underlying rate of change, is assumed to stay constant over time

$\beta =1$ gives $b_t=\ell_t - \ell_{t-1}$ so the next change is assumed to be at the rate of the last change, or as you say "the last slope"

Comment: Thank you very much!